# Is there an option to create a DAG in airflow which triggers itself on every deployment?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to create a `DAG` which triggers itself on every deployment of my application code (the `DAG`s).
I tried to assign `start_date` to now and `schedule_interval` to once, hoping it will start itself every time the DAG is built (hopefully, on every deployment):

```py
dag_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime.now(),
    'retries': 1,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'catchup': True
}
```

But it doesn't do what I wish.
(Tried `chatchup=False` as well)

Any ideas\suggestions? (I try to avoid triggering it externally)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As of Airflow 1.10.9, that is currently not possible. You will have to externally trigger the DAG when deploying it.